# Android how to make data consistent in whole app

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

I have worked on 2 or 3 android apps but in all these i have faced same problem data consistency for example I have 3 fragments with fragment pager and TabLayout

1st Tab (fragment) List of All Feeds --- fetch using web services

2nd Tab (fragment) List of Favourite feeds --- fetch using an other web services

3rd Tab (fragment) List of My Own Feeds --- fetch using an other web services

the problem is how can i make data consistent for example i have deleted one my own feed from list of All feed (1st tab) and move to List of My Own Feeds (3rd tab) by swapping then the deleted feed should not be in this list.

so how can i manage these kind of scenarios? Will i need to reload all the data in other fragment or i can manage it internally please suggest.

am not stroing data any where just parsing to custom array list and displaying them.

Thanks

Comment: Its quite unclear what your problem is. Are all tabs different data but are sharing one Adapter? Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: To avoid reloading you can cache the data from all three Web services, but what exactly do you mean to make data from 3 different Web services consistent?

Comment: @QVDev i have updated update my question

Answer (score 0):

1. using sdcard file
2. using SharePreference (the three apps have the same sign key)
3. specify the same sign key and the same android:process, run in the
   process, share data directly
4. using a Service or ContentProvider to save your perisist data
5. using system setting (data size small)
6. sendStickyBroadcast & registerReceiver

Comment: can you please explain what you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it currently you fetching 3 times partially the same data. For sure all favorite feeds contains data from all feeds. Maybe my feeds are local feeds?

I would suggest to structure it in this way:

Have one fetch for all data. This data can be structured as JSON as follow

```
[
  {"feed_id":1,"date":"17-6-16","favorite":true, "owner":true},
  {"feed_id":2,"date":"17-6-16","favorite":true, "owner":true},
  {"feed_id":3,"date":"17-6-16","favorite":false, "owner":false}
]
```

This ways you only have to fetch one time from the backend. In case this is not possible. I would suggest to merge the current three fetches into one local dataset in the application that will result in about the same structure as above.

Now you got one dataset make sure all of the lists use the same reference of the dataset. Meaning tab1, tab2 and tab3 are referencing to the same data object. Now when you remove or change data from one of these tabs, because it has the same reference it will remove it from the others as well. Just be sure you call the datasetchanged in the adapters.

Comment: your answer help me to understand this scenario thanks but what you means by "local dataset" if by local dataset you means local database then will i have to create a local database in every project? inwhich i have to keep the data synced

Comment: Local dataset in this case I meant either a database on the phone or a Object reference to the data in the application self.